Warframe JSON file
The online game warframe provides secure access to game elements via json files (description on https://warframe.fandom.com/wiki/Public_Export page). Cannot convert to array in PHP. The json file is accessed but not converted to an array.
$basis = file_get_contents("http://content.warframe.com/PublicExport/Manifest/ExportWeapons_en.json!00_mrFPI-tnYdaXwZkA8dRNaA");
$wps = json_decode($basis,true);
print(is_array($wps));

Why not an array?
How will it be an array?

The JSON is invalid, as you can see by enabling the JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR flag:
$json = file_get_contents('http://content.warframe.com/PublicExport/Manifest/ExportWeapons_en.json!00_mrFPI-tnYdaXwZkA8dRNaA');
$wps = json_decode($json, true, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);

Output:
Fatal error: Uncaught JsonException: Control character error, possibly incorrectly encoded

The file contains some raw CR/LF sequences inside strings, which is not allowed. You can fix it by just removing them:
$json = file_get_contents('http://content.warframe.com/PublicExport/Manifest/ExportWeapons_en.json!00_mrFPI-tnYdaXwZkA8dRNaA');
$json = str_replace("\r\n", '', $json);
$wps = json_decode($json, true, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);
printf('%d weapons found', count($wps['ExportWeapons']));

Output:
774 weapons found


thank you very much, it's now an array.
